# How to separate main route and alternate routes' polyline google map android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I noticed that my main route and alternate route are connected that when I set an `onclick` to it, example I just want to change my main route's color to blue, the alternate route also changes to blue. How to separate them so I can change alternate routes' and main route's colors?

This is my Fragment.java

```
public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,DirectionFinderListener,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    /**************************************************************/
    // private GoogleMap mMap;

    private ImageButton btnFindPath;
    private AutoCompleteTextView etOrigin;
    private AutoCompleteTextView etDestination;
    private List<Marker> originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Marker> destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Polyline> polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Google Places Autocomplete";
    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    private static final String API_KEY = "AIzaSyAYyvjDnsqEFVhnDflaruaTAChEzkPxpsA";

    /**************************************************************/
//FOR COLLAPSING TOOLBAR
    private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = null;

/***************************************************************/

    //**********For changing colors in the directions************************************************************/


    /**************************************************************************************************************/
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    GoogleMap mMap;

    MapView mapView;
    View Myview;

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Myview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_third_fragment, container, false);

        mapView = (MapView) Myview.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mapView.getMapAsync(this);
/********************************************************************/
        collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) Myview.findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);

        /****************************************************************************************/

        btnFindPath = (ImageButton) Myview.findViewById(R.id.btnFindPath);
        etOrigin = (AutoCompleteTextView) Myview.findViewById(R.id.etOrigin);
        etDestination = (AutoCompleteTextView) Myview.findViewById(R.id.etDestination);
        btnFindPath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendRequest();
            }
        });

        etOrigin.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item));
        etOrigin.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        etDestination.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item));
        etDestination.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        return Myview;
    }

    //**********For changing colors in the directions************************************************************/


    /**************************************************************************************************************/

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        goToLocationZoom(9.3068, 123.3054, 15);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        } else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        LatLngBounds Dumaguete = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(9.267, 123.264), new LatLng(9.33, 123.311));
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        mMap.setMinZoomPreference(15.0f);
        mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(20.0f);
        mMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(Dumaguete);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Dumaguete.getCenter(), 15));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }

    private void goToLocationZoom(double lat, double lng, int zoom) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
        mMap.moveCamera(update);

    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "entered");

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());


        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        //mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Current Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("onLocationChanged", String.format("latitude:%.3f longitude:%.3f", latitude, longitude));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Removing Location Updates");
        }
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Exit");

    }

    private void sendRequest() {
        String origin = etOrigin.getText().toString();
        String destination = etDestination.getText().toString();
        if (origin.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter origin address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (destination.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please enter destination address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            new DirectionFinder(this, origin, destination).execute();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDirectionFinderStart() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Please wait.",
                "Finding direction..!", true);

        if (originMarkers != null) {
            for (Marker marker : originMarkers) {
                marker.remove();
            }
        }

        if (destinationMarkers != null) {
            for (Marker marker : destinationMarkers) {
                marker.remove();
            }
        }

        if (polylinePaths != null) {
            for (Polyline polyline : polylinePaths) {
                polyline.remove();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> routes) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        List<Route> gRoute = new ArrayList<Route>();
        Route rr = new Route();
        gRoute.add(rr);

        List<Route> nRoute;
        nRoute = routes;

        polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
        originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
        destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < gRoute.size(); i++)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" +gRoute.size()+ "Shortest Route Found...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" +nRoute.size()+ "Route Found...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        for (final Route distance : routes)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Distance: " + distance.distance.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Directions found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        for (Route route : routes) {


            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(route.startLocation, 16));
            //  ((TextView) Myview.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration)).setText(route.duration.text);
            ((TextView) Myview.findViewById(R.id.tvDistance)).setText(route.distance.text);

            originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue))
                    .title(route.startAddress)
                    .position(route.startLocation)));
            destinationMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green))
                    .title(route.endAddress)
                    .position(route.endLocation)));


            /******************For Changing color ********************************************************/
            mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
                    // Flip the values of the red, green and blue components of the polyline's color.
                    polyline.setColor(polyline.getColor() ^ 0x00ffffff);

                }
            });

            /*************************************************************************************************/

            Random rnd = new Random();

            //int color = Coor.argb(255, 112, 112, 112);
            //int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(257), rnd.nextInt(258));

            int color = Color.parseColor("blue");
            // #999999 grey

        /**/
            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().
                    geodesic(true).color(color).width(15).clickable(true);


            for (int i = 0; i < route.points.size(); i++)
                polylineOptions.add(route.points.get(i));


            polylinePaths.add(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));

        }


    }
```

My directionfinder.java

```
public class DirectionFinder {
    private static final String DIRECTION_URL_API = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?";
    private static final String GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyC1E8NU2jjoQF7dN37bIOz_1fy0fe98YhI";
    private DirectionFinderListener listener;
    private String origin;
    private String destination;




    public DirectionFinder(DirectionFinderListener listener, String origin, String destination) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public void execute() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        listener.onDirectionFinderStart();
        new DownloadRawData().execute(createUrl());
    }

    private String createUrl() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String urlOrigin = URLEncoder.encode(origin, "utf-8");
        String urlDestination = URLEncoder.encode(destination, "utf-8");

        return DIRECTION_URL_API + "origin=" + urlOrigin + "&destination=" + urlDestination +"&alternatives=true" +"&key=" + GOOGLE_API_KEY;
    }

    private class DownloadRawData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String link = params[0];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(link);
                InputStream is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                return buffer.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String res) {
            try {
                parseJSon(res);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void parseJSon(String data) throws JSONException {
        if (data == null)
            return;

        List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
        JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray jsonRoutes = jsonData.getJSONArray("routes");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
            Route route = new Route();

            JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");
            JSONObject jsonLeg = jsonLegs.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject jsonDistance = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("distance");
            JSONObject jsonDuration = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("duration");
            JSONObject jsonEndLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("end_location");
            JSONObject jsonStartLocation = jsonLeg.getJSONObject("start_location");

            route.distance = new Distance(jsonDistance.getString("text"), jsonDistance.getInt("value"));
            route.duration = new Duration(jsonDuration.getString("text"), jsonDuration.getInt("value"));
            route.endAddress = jsonLeg.getString("end_address");
            route.startAddress = jsonLeg.getString("start_address");
            route.startLocation = new LatLng(jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonStartLocation.getDouble("lng"));
            route.endLocation = new LatLng(jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lat"), jsonEndLocation.getDouble("lng"));
            route.points = decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));

            routes.add(route);
        }

        listener.onDirectionFinderSuccess(routes);
    }

    private List<LatLng> decodePolyLine(final String poly) {
        int len = poly.length();
        int index = 0;
        List<LatLng> decoded = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        int lat = 0;
        int lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b;
            int shift = 0;
            int result = 0;
            do {
                b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            decoded.add(new LatLng(
                    lat / 100000d, lng / 100000d
            ));
        }

        return decoded;
    }
}
```

Route.java

```
public class Route {

    public Distance distance;
    public Duration duration;
    public String endAddress;
    public LatLng endLocation;
    public String startAddress;
    public LatLng startLocation;

    public List<LatLng> points;
}
```

Duration.java

```
public class Duration {

    public String text;
    public int value;

    public Duration(String text, int value) {
        this.text = text;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Distance.java

```
public class Distance {

    public String text;
    public int value;

    public Distance(String text, int value) {
        this.text = text;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

DirectionFinderListener.java

```
public interface DirectionFinderListener {
    void onDirectionFinderStart();
    void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> route);
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code you are currently working with? If you can provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example of what you are currently working with, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @Stephen okay sir. I'll update my codes.

Comment: @Stephen  sir I have updated my question and posted my codes. It is related to my other post which you answered.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop:

```
for (Route route : routes) {
```

You set the color here:

```
int color = Color.parseColor("blue");
```

This int doesn't change value when your app is drawing the polylines for each route. If you want different colors for different polylines, you will need to make changes so that this variable's value changes. For example, you could have a counter initially set to 0 in the for loop that increments each time a polyline is drawn. You could then add a conditional to set the color depending on what the count is. I'll rewrite your onDirectionsFinderSuccess function:

```
@Override
public void onDirectionFinderSuccess(List<Route> routes) {
    progressDialog.dismiss();

    int count = 0; //counter for your for each loop
    int color = Color.parseColor("blue"); //moving this here to the beginning of your function

    List<Route> gRoute = new ArrayList<Route>();
    Route rr = new Route();
    gRoute.add(rr);

    List<Route> nRoute;
    nRoute = routes;

    polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < gRoute.size(); i++)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" +gRoute.size()+ "Shortest Route Found...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" +nRoute.size()+ "Route Found...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    for (final Route distance : routes)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Distance: " + distance.distance.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Directions found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    for (Route route : routes) {


        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(route.startLocation, 16));
        //  ((TextView) Myview.findViewById(R.id.tvDuration)).setText(route.duration.text);
        ((TextView) Myview.findViewById(R.id.tvDistance)).setText(route.distance.text);

        originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.start_blue))
                .title(route.startAddress)
                .position(route.startLocation)));
        destinationMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.end_green))
                .title(route.endAddress)
                .position(route.endLocation)));


        /******************For Changing color ********************************************************/
        mMap.setOnPolylineClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPolylineClick(Polyline polyline) {
                // Flip the values of the red, green and blue components of the polyline's color.
                polyline.setColor(polyline.getColor() ^ 0x00ffffff);

            }
        });

        /*************************************************************************************************/

        Random rnd = new Random();

        //int color = Coor.argb(255, 112, 112, 112);
        //int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(257), rnd.nextInt(258));

        if(count == 0)
            color = Color.parseColor("blue");
        else if(count == 1)
            color = Color.parseColor("red");
        else
            color = Color.parseColor("green");

        //I only did this for 3 routes, but you can continue to follow this logic to color each route differently.      

        // #999999 grey

    /**/
        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions().
                geodesic(true).color(color).width(15).clickable(true);


        for (int i = 0; i < route.points.size(); i++)
            polylineOptions.add(route.points.get(i));


        polylinePaths.add(mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));
        count++;

    }


}
```

I hope this helps!